# Why is my discord.js bot replying to itself, even when I put in a check?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have been spending the last 30 minutes trying to figure out why my bot keeps on replying to itself, even when I have put in a check to prevent this.
This is my code:

```
if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + 'rps ')) {
  if(!message.author.equals(bot.user)) {
    let theirInp = message.content.substring(prefix.length + 4)
    let botInp = rpsTab[Math.floor(Math.random() * rpsTab.length)];

    if (!theirInp == "") {
      if (wins[botInp] == theirInp) {
        message.channel.send("I won!")
      } else if (botInp == theirInp) {
        message.channel.send("We tied!")
      } else {
        message.channel.send("You won!")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a different conditional expression.

```
if(!message.author.bot){...}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Answer

`message.author.user` equals to [User](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User)
While `bot.user` equals [ClientUser](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser)
 
And they are 2 separate objects. Therefore these 2 different objects dont match and therefore fail the `.equals()`

## Recommended Fix

As @Frost said to use `author.bot`:

```
if(message.author.bot) return
```

is way simpler as it just exits when the it's a bot and you don't have to deal with indenting some more code by placing it in an `if` statement 
And you won't have to worry about other bots using your commands

## Fix your code

To fix your code just swap

```
 if(!message.author.equals(bot.user)) {}
```

to

```
 if(message.author.id !== bot.user.id){}
```